# Distributed DataBase with NeoDatis ODB

Tags: database, distributed

I'm using the Neodatis ODB Database in my new system. Everything works fine, but I would like to make a Distributed Database.

Does anyone knows how can I make that using Neodatis Database(A Database Master Server and his slaves in different computers)?

Answer (score 1):

you can have a look at NeoDatis V2 that can be configured to run as a distributed database :

http://www.neodatis.org/neodatisv2